# Lilypond: How to control the paper size to create images

Tags: lilypond

My question concerns the creation of images using lilypond. Until know I've created some music sheets and lilypond has been really great. However I have a website and I would like to post some examples to illustrate what I'm saying. The images should just fit the size of what is written. It will mostly been 2-3 bars max, but I would like the size to fit automatically as it could be bigger.

When I use the --png option, it creates an image the size of an A4 page. I tried using the snippets shown in the doc, for exemple here : http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.12/input/lsr/12/lily-1ed76b9d.ly

If I comment the *\include "lilypond-book-preamble.ly"*, then it shows as an A4 document.
If I leave it, then I'm asked to add *-dbackend=eps* to the command line. If I add it, then **it actually produces the result i'm searching for.** However it also adds a whole bunch of files (multiple .pdf, .eps, .tex, .texi, .count).

Is there a proper way to do it, or should I write a bash script to clean the folder after the lilypond command?

Another thing: with the **--png option**, are we able to define an image size? I'm able to change it using *-dresolution* but it's not very handy as you have to try to see the output size, then change and try again...
Maybe is it better to create .pdf and use other scripts to convert into .png?

Thank you in advance! I searched for this information but found very little about it so far...

Comment: Note that your link is to the documentation for the v2.12 version of the software.  You may want to consider using a newer version, or looking at the documentation for the version that you are using.

Comment: Note that cross posting the same question on multiple sites is frowned upon, c.f. (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: Sorry, i'm new here. I read several posts that said lilypond questions could belong in both, not that it was limited to one. Won't happen again. I also updated my lilypond version (the one in the depository is deprecated).

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/96970/lilypond-is-there-a-way-to-auto-crop-the-paper

Answer (score 2):

I use the following as my header (since version 2.16):

```
\paper{
    indent=0\mm
    line-width=120\mm
    oddFooterMarkup=##f
    oddHeaderMarkup=##f
    bookTitleMarkup = ##f
    scoreTitleMarkup = ##f
    }
    \relative c' { c4 d e f | g a b c }
```

and compile it using `lilypond -dbackend=eps -dno-gs-load-fonts -dinclude-eps-fonts --png test.ly`. The resulting png files fit to the music.  This does produce the extraneous (mostly TeX related) files; I do not know of a way around that.

Comment: Thanks, this gives me the expected result! However it also gives a lot of files I won't use (.eps, .tex, ...). Is there a way to handle it with lilypond or am I better off using rm?

Comment: @Fnor Combing the documentation reveals the `-ddelete-intermediate-files` flag. Does this do what you want? Failing that, you could always wrap lilypond in a shell script that copies the file to a temporary directory renders it, copies the result back, and deletes temporary directory again.

Answer (score 2):

I would add to Dave's answer that if you want to have everything in a single system and you don't want to care about the width and height settings, you could just put

`page-breaking = #ly:one-line-breaking`

into your `\paper` block. That will cause the width and height settings to be ignored and all of the music typeset in a single system, with no whitespace at the borders.